# What's the dimension of $\mathbb C$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: vector-spaces

What's the dimension of $\mathbb C$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

I think that the answer is $2$, because $\mathbb R^2 \cong \mathbb{C}$ (since all complex numbers can be mapped to $\mathbb R^2$ and vice versa).

Is this correct, or is it a trick question (in which case I'm wrong)?

Comment: You are correct, but a little non-rigorous.  What do you mean by "all complex numbers can be mapped to $\Bbb R^2$ and visa versa"? Do you mean that there exists some bijection between them?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes. I mean that there's a 1-1 correspondence between $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb{C}.$ Is this new phrase more rigorous?

Comment: It's still not good enough.  There is a 1-1 correspondence between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^2$ (i.e. they have the same cardinality), but these are not isomorphic vector spaces.  What's special about $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb R^2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
$\lbrace 1,i\rbrace$ is a basis.

As for what you have said, there is an isomorphism $$\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle x^2+1\rangle}\simeq \mathbb{C}$$ where $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is the polynomial ring.

Comment: Therefore, the dimension is $2$, yes?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 8):

Note that $\mathbf{R}^m$ is bijective with $\mathbf{R}^n$ for all $m,n > 0$, so the explicit argument you gave doesn't work.

However, there is more to the identification $\mathbf{R}^2 \cong \mathbf{C}$ than simply being a bijection... what you're trying to show is that it's actually a linear transformation between $\mathbf{R}$-vector spaces!